# print strings recursively, depending on how many items are added in multiple lists

Tags: python, recursion, dynamic

My program prints out 3 columns...

```
column_1      column_2      column_3
```

Each column corresponds to a list of varying length. Basically, I print out the columns as a header, then print out something under each column, but each time the program is ran, the list lengths will vary. I can't import a column library to construct the columns, I ran in to other issues that way.

To check the longest list, I have this code. This solves the issue of knowing how many lines to print each time, as column with most lines will equal the total lines to print...

```
def longest_list(x):

    list_len = [len(i) for i in x]
    print(max(list_len))
```

The next piece in the puzzle is to print each line with each lists item in place.
I thought to do something like this:

```
if len(list_1) == 1:
    print(f'{list_1[0]}      {list_2[0]}      {list_3[0]}'
```

I had to place a string placeholder in each list for index position 0, otherwise an error will be returned if one is empty, which is a possibility.

I do not know how I should scale this up in the right way. Let's say *list_1* has 1 item, *list_2* 10 items and *list_3* 4 items, **how can I dynamically/recursively check and then print out the correct strings?** We would need 10 lines in that case, line one being index 0, line two returning empty for list_1, index 2 for list_2/list_3 and so on. Any thoughts?

**edit** sample input/output

string INPUT

```
hello
```

output

```
column_1      column_2      column_3

word_1        word_2        word_3
              word_4        word_5
              word_6        word_7
              word_8
              word_9
```

words from column_1 belong to list_1, column_2 list_2 and column_3 to list_3.

Comment: Can you give an example of an input and the expected output?

Comment: Sure, I will edit now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like the following. The key is the get_row_value function, which just returns an empty string if the list doesn't have an entry for the given row. Also note the use of ljust(col_width) to keep the cells spaced out evenly, even if the string values in each cell are different lengths.

```
def get_row_value(col_list, row_num):
    return col_list[row_num] if len(col_list) > row_num else ''

col_lists = [col_1, col_2, col_3]
max_length = max(len(col_list) for col_list in col_lists)
col_width = 10 # set this to whatever you want
for row_num in range(0, max_length):
    row_str = ''
    for col_list in col_lists:
        row_value = get_row_value(col_list, row_num)
        row_str += row_value.ljust(col_width)
    print(row_str)
```